# Module not found in AWS EMR slave nodes

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, apache-spark, pyspark, emr

I am currently running `spark-submit` jobs on an AWS EMR cluster. I started running into python package issues where a module is not found in during imports.

One obvious solution would be to go into each individual node and install my dependencies. I would like to avoid this if possible. Another solution I can do is write a bootstrap script and create a new cluster.

Last solution that seems to work is I can also `pip install` my dependencies and zip them and pass them through the `spark-submit` job through `--py-files`. Though that may start becoming cumbersome as my requirements increase.

Any other suggestions or easy fixes I may be overlooking?

Comment: I would go with the bootstrap method - script saved on s3. It will be easy to make changes if you need to do so in the future.

Comment: @Abi do you know if the bootstrap is run every time I submit a job? Or how does it work? I was under the impression that it's only run in the beginning when I create a cluster but that seems wrong as well.

Comment: You are right! It is executed only when starting up the cluster. Do you manually submit the jobs after creating a cluster? What is your workflow?

Answer (score 0):

bootstrap is the solution. write a shell script, pip install all your required packages and put it in the bootstrap option. It will be executed on all nodes when you create a cluster. just keep in mind that if the bootstrap takes too long time (1 hour or so?), it will fail.

Comment: To my knowledge, the bootstrap script runs once only when the cluster is created so it doesn't play well with scaling clusters up and down. We are opting for Mesos to manage containers with appropriate dependencies that way.